# Django: update isn't saving the record to the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
def registrar(request):
    form = RegForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            b = form.cleaned_data['folioboleto']
            n = form.cleaned_data['nombre']
            aP = form.cleaned_data['apellidoPaterno']
            aM = form.cleaned_data['apellidoMaterno']
            fecha = form.cleaned_data['fechaDeNacimiento']
            g = form.cleaned_data['genero']
            e = form.cleaned_data['email']
            tel = form.cleaned_data['telefono']
            di = form.cleaned_data['direccion']
            c = form.cleaned_data['ciudad']
            est = form.cleaned_data['estado']
            actP = form.cleaned_data['actividadPrincipal']
            cSE = form.cleaned_data['comoSupoEvento']
            aF = form.cleaned_data['aceptoFotos']

            obj = Cliente.objects.create(Nombre=n,ApellidoPaterno=aP,ApellidoMaterno=aM,FechaDeNacimiento=fecha,Genero=g,Email=e,Telefono=tel,Direccion=di,Ciudad=c,Estado=est,ActividadPrincipal=actP,ComoSupoEvento=cSE,AceptoFotos=aF)

            bole = Boleto.objects.get(Folio=b)
            if bole.Folio == b:
                bole.Estatus = '2'
                bole.Cliente_id = obj.id 
                bole.save(update_fields=['Estatus'])
```

The object `bole` save method isn't saving the changes to the database.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is with `bole.save(update_fields=['Estatus'])`, which would only update the field named `Estatus`, which doesn't seem to be being set. Try just using a bare save instead:

```
bole.save()
```

Good luck!

Comment: Continue without saving the data.

What I try is to update my Boleto object in those 2 fields of Estatus and Client_id, since Client_id is a Foreign Key

Comment: bole = Boleto.objects.filter(Folio = b).update(Estatus = '2', Cliente_id = obj.id)

Comment: It would help to see your models, but this is often a point of confusion. For the `ForeignKey` you want to point to an object instance, not an id. Try: `bole.cliente = obj` if you have it defined in your `Boleto` model as `cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)`.

Comment: If I remove the bole.Client_id, if you update the Status field, but if I leave the Client_id, it does not do any updates.

Comment: My model Boleto contains this :

Comment: Cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, blank = False, null = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

Comment: for bole in Boleto.objects.filter(Folio=b):
                bole.Estatus = '2'
                bole.save(update_fields=['Estatus'])